Streamlit - Text color in Menu
When I'm on page 'X' in the menu, the background color changes to a darker shade, and the text turns solid black. However, on the other pages, the text appears in a lighter black, almost as if there's a transparency effect. How can I make all the text in the menu solid black?
I've created the sidebar by creating a folder named pages with the pages. I've tried to change the config.toml textColor to textColor = "#000000", but it didn't work.
What other solution could solve this?
I'm calling the sidebar by the set_page_config
st.set_page_config(page_title='Ibyct', initial_sidebar_state='expanded', layout="wide")

In the image you can see clearer what I'm talking about


I think it's a geasture that this page is active.

Yes! It is, but I want to make all of the texts to be black. I would like that the active page would go black + bold + different blackground as it is. That grey/light black in the unactives didn't work out well for my purpose. But thanks for the note! I don't know if it is possible, I've searched here in the forum, but I've only found how to change the background color in the sidebar.
